# Setting sqlite temp store directory

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a Python binary which uses SQLite as its backend database. SQLite's documentation and the code suggests that setting any of the following 3 environment variables should work:

```
export TMP=/var/tmp/sqlite/
export TEMP=/var/tmp/sqlite/
export TEMPDIR=/var/tmp/sqlite/
```

If I export the above variables in my bash script just before I start my Python binary, it does not help.

Another option I tried is calling `putenv()` by setting `os.environ`:

```
os.environ['TMP'] = /var/tmp/sqlite/
os.environ['TEMP'] = /var/tmp/sqlite/
os.environ['TEMPDIR'] = /var/tmp/sqlite/
```

None of above options has helped in persuading SQLite to use `/var/tmp/sqlite` as its temp store directory. The only option that has worked - which SQLite's documentation says is deprecated - is setting the `temp_store_directory` pragma statement:

```
PRAGMA temp_store_directory = '/egnyte/.work/sqlite_temp'
```

Since using the pragma statement is not the choice I would like to make, is there any other trick?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The environment variables you are referring to are indeed what sqlite looks for but in Windows, not UNIX.

In Unix, the environment variable you need to set is `TMPDIR` as shown in the sources:

```
static const char *unixTempFileDir(void){
  static const char *azDirs[] = {
     0,
     0,
     "/var/tmp",
     "/usr/tmp",
     "/tmp",
     0        /* List terminator */
  };
  unsigned int i;
  struct stat buf;
  const char *zDir = 0;

  azDirs[0] = sqlite3_temp_directory;
  if( !azDirs[1] ) azDirs[1] = getenv("TMPDIR");
  for(i=0; i<sizeof(azDirs)/sizeof(azDirs[0]); zDir=azDirs[i++]){
    if( zDir==0 ) continue;
    if( osStat(zDir, &buf) ) continue;
    if( !S_ISDIR(buf.st_mode) ) continue;
    if( osAccess(zDir, 07) ) continue;
    break;
  }
  return zDir;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

For version 3.8.1+ (released October 2013), it's cleaner to use the new `SQLITE_TMPDIR` environment variable instead of `TMPDIR`, since the latter is used by Unix software other than SQLite.

From the [release notes](https://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_8_1.html):

> The directory used to hold temporary files on unix can now be set using the SQLITE_TMPDIR environment variable, which takes precedence over the TMPDIR environment variable. The sqlite3_temp_directory global variable still has higher precedence than both environment variables, however.

Comment: for the sqlite3 version 3.16.2 2017-01-06 16:32:41 a65a62893ca8319e89e48b8a38cf8a59c69a8209, setting both TMPDIR and SQLITE_TMPDIR will cause non-working condition. both variable values will be ignored.