# sqlite3 disk usage while indexing a database

Tags: python, ubuntu, sqlite

When I called `sqlite3.connect('db').execute('CREATE INDEX ...')`, my `/` partition became full and the script crashed with `sqlite3.OperationalError: database or disk is full`.

I have two partitions: `/` with 4GB free, `/home` with 1TB free. The python script is under `/home`.

How can I tell `sqlite3` to use `/home` partition instead of `/` for its temporary files?

When I tried to see what files are being created under `/` while the python script was running, I found this:

```
python    24853 max    6u   REG    8,1 3821580012  788060 /var/tmp/etilqs_xARlZag1jj945jH (deleted)
```

Not sure what "deleted" means, but it seems to be the source of the problem.

Ubuntu 14.04LTS
Python 3.5

UPDATE: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23251896/336527 solved it.

Comment: I think it's using `/var/tmp` for temporary files, not the root directory

Comment: I think you need the answer from [Setting sqlite temp store directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10394517/setting-sqlite-temp-store-directory)

Comment: @cricket_007 yes, but it's in the root filesystem (partition). I want it to use the `/home` filesystem (partition).

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen yes it worked.