# How to change sqlite database to create temporary files in any other folder instead of temp folder using JAVA?

Tags: java, database, sqlite, environment-variables

I am using SQLite database within my JAVA application in which I create database on runtime and then create tables and perform different DB operations, as SQLite has to create its temporary files somewhere, and the temporary directory is the directory that is designed to hold such files, currently in my windows OS environment SQLite is creating files in TEMP folder, I need to change the folder in any other location other than C drive.
I have tried following operations

1. Change Environment variable values of `TEMP` and `TMP` in mentioned following question [How can I change the temp folder where sqlite creates etilqs files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16122824/how-can-i-change-the-temp-folder-where-sqlite-creates-etilqs-files)
2. Add new Environment variable `SQLITE_TMPDIR` and `TMPDIR` mentioned in following question
   [Setting sqlite temp store directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10394517/setting-sqlite-temp-store-directory)
3. I tried `PRAGMA` statements according to following SQLite documentation
   https://www.sqlite.org/tempfiles.html

`PRAGMA temp_store_directory = 'D:\SQLite-TMP';`

```
I have also tried with following piece of code but it didn't worked for me
Connection obj_connection = null;
        Statement obj_statement = null;
        try {
            m_objLogManager.logInfo("Creating table 'QUEUE' if not exist ...");
            obj_connection = getConnection();
            m_objLogManager.logInfo("Execute PRAGMA");
            try(Statement statement = obj_connection.createStatement()) {
                m_objLogManager.logInfo("going to Execute PRAGMA");
                statement.execute("PRAGMA temp_store_directory = 'D:\\SQLite-TMP';");
                m_objLogManager.logInfo("Execute PRAGMA successfully");
            }
            try(Statement statement = obj_connection.createStatement()) {
                m_objLogManager.logInfo("getting PRAGMA");
                try(ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("PRAGMA temp_store_directory;")) {
                    m_objLogManager.logInfo("getting PRAGMA successfull");
                    m_objLogManager.logInfo(rs.getString(1));
                }
            }
            obj_statement = obj_connection.createStatement();
            String str_sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS QUEUE " +
                    "(Id VARCHAR(200) PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL," +
                    " Origin            TEXT, " +
                    " Port              INT, " +
                    " RegisterAt        TEXT, " +
                    " UserName        TEXT)";
            obj_statement.executeUpdate(str_sql);
            m_objLogManager.logInfo("Table 'QUEUE' is created if not exist");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw ex;
        } finally {
            if (obj_statement != null) {
                obj_statement.close();
            }
            if (obj_connection != null) {
                obj_connection.close();
            }
        }
```

I also open my DB file in SQLite browser and execute following query
`PRAGMA temp_store_directory = 'D:\SQLite-TMP';`
But still SQLite creating temporary files in TEMP folder I want to change the location of temporary files into `D:\SQLite-TMP` this folder.
can anyone helped me as i am stuck in this problem, please let me know how to set the global variable `sqlite3_temp_directory` because I don't understand how to set it up from official [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/temp_directory.html) thanks.

My Environment

- Windows 10
- Sqlite database
- JAVA 11

Answer (score 0):

First, pragma `temp_store_directory` is deprecated (see [this](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_temp_store_directory)), so might not work anymore.

Second, `SQLITE_TMPDIR` and `TMPDIR` are for unix-like OSs, and looks like you're on Windows.

So I would try to set the global variable `sqlite3_temp_directory` as mentioned [here](https://www.sqlite.org/tempfiles.html) at the bottom.

Hope this helps.

Comment: could you please guide how and where to set this sqlite3_temp_directory variable as I am not getting understanding from documentation, should i code in java or set in sqlite configuration etc ?

Comment: If i need to set in java code then can you please provide me code snippet

Comment: I suggest that you google what is a global variable in Windows. And I suppose that even if it is possible to set it from Java code, that would not be a good idea overall.